# Python: How can I send files from a remote server to a local client

Tags: python, linux, file, server, client

I want to send files from my remote server to (a cloud linux machine) a local client (my machine). I have tried to use paramiko, but I just don't find it to have enough functionality. Please, if you have anything could help me then I would love to here it.

Comment: Can you please specify your requirements? the `scp` way that you used with `paramiko` seems good to me.

Comment: you could just run `python -m http.server` but thats not very secure obviously

Comment: @ParhamAlvani What do you mean requirements? I am running just Python 3.9 with a linux server and local host.

Comment: I am your requirements for file transfer that SCP cannot cover for you

Comment: @ParhamAlvani SCP can do everything I need. Except that I do not want it to have to be installed on the local client.

Comment: Oh, sorry for miss understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest way is to use the scp command.

Here is an example:

scp user@remote.server.com:/path/to/file /local/path/to/save/file

You will need to replace the user@remote.server.com and /path/to/file with the appropriate values for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I really wanted for the local client not to have scp installed. Thank you.

Comment: If local machine is windows you can use mobaxterm it can easily do drag and drop from remote server